# How to test performance only for a specific section in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am working on a template where we import items from a tool we use in our company called Jama. One of the items we import from there is Decriptions. In this part we have a conversion of HTML to Text which seems slow to us and I need to do a Timing analysis before.
I am very new in this and I dont know where and how to use the sources I find online.

Here is the code regarding descriptions:

```
sPastCellContant = rCell.Offset (0, cDescription - 1)
rCell.Offset( 0, cDescription - 1) = HtmlToText (oResponseDataFields ("description"))
If rCell.Offset (0,Description - 1) <> sPastCellContant Then
   rCell.Offset (0,Description - 1).Interior.ColorIndex = ChangedColour
End If
```

**Update**

@Peh Sorry, I missed that. Its not working. Anyway I added CTimer as a module in my project. After this I declared StopWatch As New CTimer. How the code looks now:

```
StopWatch.StartCounter

sPastCellContant = rCell.Offset (0, cDescription - 1)
rCell.Offset( 0, cDescription - 1) = HtmlToText (oResponseDataFields ("description"))
If rCell.Offset (0,Description - 1) <> sPastCellContant Then
   rCell.Offset (0,Description - 1).Interior.ColorIndex = ChangedColour
End If

Debug.Print "Requesting Data from Jama server too" & StopWatch.TimeElapsed & "ms" 
StopWatch.StartCounter
```

It shows in the "Immediate" how many ms too to request data from jama but I do not understand yet if it is working only for the description part. I solve it depending on an similar example with Jira.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/861/debugging-and-troubleshooting/6187/use-timer-to-find-bottlenecks-in-performance and please don't post updates as answer. You can edit your question and add them as update to the question instead.

Comment: @Peh yes it works for the description. Do you have any suggestion how I can improve the speed of the conversion of HTML to Text? Does VBA provides something regarding to this?

Comment: @ande no one can know this if we don't see what is behind the `HtmlToText()` function. You need to show that code first.

Comment: `Function HtmlToText(sHTML) As String
  Dim oDoc As HTMLDocument
  Set oDoc = New HTMLDocument
  oDoc.body.innerHTML = sHTML
  HtmlToText = oDoc.body.innerText
End Function` @Peh

Comment: Ok, please edit the question next time to add code. Nonetheless my answer is no, I don't see any chance to make this code faster. Excel was invented for calculating tables and not for being misused as an alternative programming language doing fancy things. If you are improving for speed you can only use a real programming language like C++ or C# and write a real program. Excel might just be the wrong tool then.

Comment: @Peh, you may be right but my supervisor is asking this from me. And he says its very easy to be solved! I really dont know what to do. Sorry also for not writing correctly here, I am not used! So sorry guys

Comment: If he says it is easy then why doesn't he say how? Why don't you ask him if it is that easy? I don't see any easier way to come from HTML to text than using `oDoc.body.innerText`. But you can check if the slowing part is `oResponseDataFields ("description")` or the `HtmlToText()` function.

Comment: @Peh I checked and the slowing part is html to text. He doesn't tell me. I dont want to make the situation too emotional but Im about to quit my job because of this awful stressful situation. ...And I am so sorry for being so boring :(

Comment: Can you try `rCell.Offset( 0, cDescription - 1) = HtmlToText (oResponseDataFields ("description"))` versus `rCell.Offset( 0, cDescription - 1) = oResponseDataFields ("description")` line and post both times it takes to run them?

Comment: @Peh I am not at work today but as far as I remember it took 19,278482724ms vs.  0,3774821683ms or 16,928463828ms vs.1,3847735781ms etc.  I invented the nr after comma.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `debug.print oResponseDataFields ("description")` so I can test it? Because I used the source code of this website here and run a test with  `HtmlToText()` and it took 0.16685 seconds so please check your units if this is really 16ms this is quite fast.

Comment: @Peh we decided to let it as it is. I want to thank you so so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the microtimer

```
Private Declare Function getFrequency Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "QueryPerformanceFrequency" (cyFrequency As Currency) As Long
Private Declare Function getTickCount Lib "kernel32" _
Alias "QueryPerformanceCounter" (cyTickCount As Currency) As Long

Function MicroTimer() As Double
    ' Returns seconds.

    Dim cyTicks1 As Currency
    Static cyFrequency As Currency

    MicroTimer = 0

    ' Get frequency.
    If cyFrequency = 0 Then getFrequency cyFrequency

    ' Get ticks.
    getTickCount cyTicks1                            

    ' Seconds
    If cyFrequency Then MicroTimer = cyTicks1 / cyFrequency 
End Function
```

Example how to use it:

```
Sub CalculationTestSub()
    Dim dTime as Double

    ' Get start time.
        dTime = MicroTimer

    ' ### Do your time consumptive stuff here

    ' Calculate duration.
        dTime = MicroTimer - dTime
        On Error GoTo 0

        dTime = Round(dTime, 5)
        MsgBox "Calculation Time: " & CStr(dTime) & " Seconds", _
            vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "CalcTimer"
End Sub
```

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730921.aspx

Comment: I do not know how to make it work for my code. Can you explain me a little bit?

Comment: I added a sample code to my answer. Some more sample code is in the link at the end of my answer. Also explanation how to use it (start reading at: Measuring Calculation Time).